# Website Overlay, Is It Possible?

Tags: web, overlay

Can anyone come up with a solution?

We sell phone systems from a supplier www.voipstudio.com

Our customers login to their account at www.voipstudio.com/login

We want to hide everything around the login page so it only shows the login details.

Is there anyway to over white boxes around the login dialog box?

This picture shows how it currently looks

[image]

This picture shows how we would like it shown

[image]

Is there any way to maybe load pop up boxes over the sections that we don't want the customers to see or another method?

Comment: Can you not add css to the page? Or remove the html?

Comment: Well you never answered so I went ahead and gave you a solution for either situation. Let me know if you have anymore questions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided and the page that you referenced in your question. If you add this css to your css file it will hide all of the divs you want to not be on your page.

This works because I am using the css to not show the data.

```
.page-id-653 .main-image {
    display: none !important;
}

.page-id-653 .dark-bg {
    display: none !important;
}

.page-id-653 .ft-button {
    display: none !important;
}

.page-id-653 .site-footer {
    display: none !important;
}

.page-id-653 .ft-button-twitter {
    display: none !important;
}

.page-id-653 .ft-button-facebook {
    display: none !important;
}

.page-id-653 .vs-page .header {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Please notice that I added the class `.page-id-653`.
The reason I did this is to make sure we don't hide the data on any other page besides this specific page.

In order to enter the css please go to 
Appearance / editor / style.css
From your Wordpress Dashboard

If you do not have access to this site and you are trying to serve it up with an iframe you could attach the id of the area you want to show to the url.

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://voipstudio.com/en/login/#l7p-login-form" width=400 height=400></iframe>
```

The social media sidebar they have on the page was acting a little difficult for me but this one of these answers should get you twoards one of the best solutions for your situation.

There are many ways you can get tricky with `iframes`. I suggest searching SO for more on, "position iframe on specific points".